# Rank different countries in Game Center Leaderboard?

Tags: ios, game-center, country, leaderboard

I was wondering if it would be possible to rank things other than individual player in Game Center, such as a country. It would be set up so that when a player gets a score, it adds that score to the player's country score and that gets sent to Game Center.  So, would this be feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Game Center views do not offer filtering other than what you see in the standard interface (time scope and all players vs. all friends).  So, to get this behavior, you would need to build your own custom Game Center leaderboard interface, manually downloading scores with `GKLeaderboard`, and storing and retrieving country information in the hidden `context` parameter of scores.

However... this would be hugely impractical, because you would have to download a very large number of scores to ensure that you would capture even most of the countries where players have submitted scores. As such, you really should look into having your own leaderboard server which tracks the data you're interested in, and can efficiently return it organized in the way of your choosing.